# Image button click event not firing in chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, imagebutton

I noticed that in chrome if you have an asp.net image button and do a mouse down then a mouse move and finally a mouse up, a click event is not fired. It works in other browsers. Does any body have a work around to this ???

Comment: are you sure about this ?@vignesh

Comment: @Devjosh http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms14.htm. You can try that link. Click and drag over the image button and release. In other browsers it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because chrome starts a select/drag behavior when you do that. Try the following css.

```
html, body, div, span, object, form, input, h1, h2, button, label, a, img
{
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* this will work for QtWebKit in future */
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

Comment: There is also a javascript workaraound in this page. http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_disable_dragging_of_images_and_text_selection_in_web_pages