# ImageButton Click Event is not Fired with Google Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, google-chrome

In my asp.net project there is a ImageButton inside a user control. In Google chrome when I click the button nothing happens, *in ff and ie no problem* but chrome doesn't do anything. I have put a breakpoint in the event's method but it doesn't even come into that method. Any ideas? My chrome version is 12.0.742.122 and ImageButton is not inside an UpdatePanel. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add another break point in OnInit or OnLoad method to check whether there is a postback and the problem is with the OnClick method only?

Comment: Regardless of what you originally wrote it in, it has to be HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for the browser to understand it.  What's your onclick event handler, or, if it's submitting a form, what's your form's action property set to.

Comment: Try disabling asp.net validators if you have any

Comment: @ersan open the inspect alement and check for javascript errors.

Comment: did you see that ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703822/image-button-click-event-not-firing-in-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a noob situation here. My front end developer friend had put the ImageButton inside an html "a" tag. So Chrome actually goes to a's href url. I have removed the "a" and it worked.

Comment: Kind of interesting that in all of the other browsers they skipped over the "a" tag...I'm assuming that your front end developer left the href property out of the "a" tag?

Comment: nope href was in a's attributes. But ImageButton was in "a" tag too.